# Evaluating the series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{2+\frac{(-\sqrt{2})^k}{5^2}}{5^k}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

We want to evaluate the value of this series:

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{2+\frac{(-\sqrt{2})^k}{5^2}}{5^k}$$

So far, I have

$$ = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\frac{2\cdot25}{25}+\frac{(-\sqrt{2})^k}{25}}{5^k} \\
= 2\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{ (-\sqrt{2})^k}{5^k} \\
= 2\sum_{k=0}^\infty \bigl( \frac{ -\sqrt{2}}{5} \bigr)^k $$

How does one continue from here? Did I make a mistake?

Comment: When you write $2.25$, did you mean $2\times25$? And where does the final equality come from?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Yes, I expanded by $25$ to get the common denominator. I just divided $50$ by $25$ and got $2$, which I put in front of the sum

Comment: I don't see how the sum $\frac{2\cdot25}{25}+\frac{(-\sqrt{2})^k}{25}$ vanishes. Or what happens to the $\frac1{25}$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Yes, sorry I made a mistake there. I can't cancel them out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{2+\frac{(-\sqrt{2})^k}{5^2}}{5^k}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(\frac{2}{5^k}+\frac{1}{5^2}(\frac{-\sqrt2}{5})^k)=_{(1)}2\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{5^k}+\frac{1}{5^2}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(\frac{-\sqrt2}{5})^k=\frac{5}{2}+\frac{1}{25+5\sqrt 2}$$

$(1)$ We can do this because both of them are absolutely convergent

Comment: That was faster than the speed of light!

Comment: How do you get to the last part, i.e., $\frac{5}{2} + \frac{1}{25+5\sqrt{2}}$?

Comment: Just applying the geometric sum formula for $1/5$ and $-\sqrt 2/5$ respectively